# Separar una cadena json, guardando en variables con su respectivo valor

Tags: c#, json, string

Este es el resultado de la consulta a un webservice

```
{"Nombre":"Juan","Apellido":"Luna","Edad":26,"FechaNacimiento":"09/03/1990 12:00:00 AM"}
```

Necesito de alguna forma separar los valores y guardarlos con el nombre de la variable y el valor que le corresponde, estoy haciéndolo en c# he logrado la separación de los elementos, pero no he podido crear variables y asignar valores, cabe mencionar que en algun momento lo que traiga el json puede cambiar, pueden ser mas o menos valores de eso no tengo el control, por eso quiero separarlos de manera dinamica y de igual forma asignarlos.

```
EsValido = "{\"Nombre\":\"Juan\",\"Apellido\":\"Luna\",\"Edad\":26,\"FechaNacimiento\":\"09/03/1990 12:00:00 AM\"}";
EsValido = EsValido.Replace(":", "");

String value = EsValido.Trim();

if (value.IndexOf("JUAN") != -1)
{
    string[] delimiter = { ",", "{", "}", "\"" };
    string[] substrings = value.Split(delimiter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    for (int i = 0; i < substrings.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            Response.Write(substrings[i] + "<br/>");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Creo que tu pregunta no es clara, ¿deseas crear una clase de forma dinámica a partir del JSON que recibes? O, ¿Los valores que recibes en el JSON deseas guardarlos en una clase que ya existe y está definida?

Answer (score 2):

¡Hola! es sencillo lo primero que debes hacer es convertir tu cadena a su notacion en Objetos y los haces de esta manera:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public int Edad { get; set; }
    public string FechaNacimiento { get; set; }
}
```

Ahora, ya teniendo el objeto solo te queda convertir tu JSON String en este objeto ¿Verdad? para esa magia hay 2 formas, utilizando el conversor nativo de c# y la libreria [Newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) te dejo las 2 soluciones:

Usando [NewtonSoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
string tuString = "{\"Nombre\":\"Juan\",\"Apellido\":\"Luna\",\"Edad\":26,\"FechaNacimiento\":\"09/03/1990 12:00:00 AM\"}";
RootObject m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(tuString);

string name = m.Nombre;
Console.WriteLine(name);
```

Ahora con el nativo de C#:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

RootObject data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(tuString);
```

Saludos!

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, la separación como ustedes lo mencionan ya la he hecho, utilizando Newtonsoft.Json, aquí tomo los valores fijos que por ahora me arroja, pero si en algún momento el contenido del json cambia, si le agregan o le quitan valores o el último de los casos yo no sepa que valores trae el json, como poder separarlos sin llegar a saber el contenido, quizá sea algo ilógico, pero quiero ver si existe la forma.

Comment: `Newtonsoft` lo tiene funciona así: `dynamic d = JObject.Parse("{number:1000, str:'string', array: [1,2,3,4,5,6]}");

Console.WriteLine(d.number);
Console.WriteLine(d.str);
Console.WriteLine(d.array.Count);`

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo, lo que quieres hacer (en C#) es recibir un JSON y guardarlo en un objeto tipo

```
class Persona{
    string Nombre = "Juan";
    string Apellido = "Luna";
    int Edad = 26;
    DateTime FechaNacimiento = "09/03/1990";
}
```

Si ese es el caso, no te quiebres la cabeza; existe la librería [Json de Newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) que procesa el Json por ti, solo debes ir a su [documentación](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/R_Project_Documentation.htm)  para experimentar y ver cuál es la solución.

De entrada te digo que necesitas tener un objeto como el de arriba pero con `get` y `set`:

```
public class Persona{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public int Edad { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaNacimiento { get; set; }
}
```

y luego tratar tu Json con [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm):

```
var personaIntermedioObject = JObject.Parse(el_json);
```

para finalmente asignar al modelo `Persona` los datos:

```
Persona persona = new Persona(){
    Nombre = personaIntermedioObject["Nombre"].ToString(),
    Apellido = personaIntermedioObject["Apellido"].ToString(),
    Edad = Convert.ToInt32(personaIntermedioObject["Edad"]),
    FechaNacimiento = (DateTime)personaIntermedioObject["FechaNacimiento"]
}
```

O bien intentar parsearlo directamente con

```
Persona persona = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Persona>(el_json);
```

EDIT:
Creo que entiendo tu pregunta. Lo que vas a recibir es un JSON que puede ser cualquier estructura, no solo la que diste de ejemplo, estilo

```
{nombre:"Juan",edad:"24"}
{estado:"Guanajuato",ciudad:"Celaya"}
```

y mostrarlos (o usarlos) como

```
Propiedad | Valor       Propiedad | Valor
---------------------   -----------------------
   nombre | Juan           estado | Guanajuato
     edad | 24             ciudad | Celaya
```

En ese caso, siguiendo con Json de Newtonsoft, necesitas un ciclo que recorra cada una de las parejas de Clave:Valor del Json. Un ejemplo que almacena los datos en un *diccionario* es:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object> dic = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>();
foreach(JProperty obj in personaIntermedioObject.Properties())
{
    dic.Add(obj.Name, obj.Value);
    // O bien, imprimirlos en consola:
    Console.WriteLine("Clave: {0} | Valor: {1}", obj.Name, obj.Value.ToString())
}
```

De esa manera, puedes almacenar la información que sea, del tamaño que sea, en una estructura que puedes utilizar posteriormente.

Mi referencia: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522358/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-keys-from-json-net#6529408

---

EDIT 2:

Hasta donde sé, no puedes crear variables "al aire" (on the fly), lo más parecido que puedes hacer es usar un objeto [`dynamic`](https://www.dotnetperls.com/dynamic) de la siguiente manera:

```
dynamic DynObj = JObject.Parse(el_json);
```

De esa manera, puedes consultar sobre `DynObj.Nombre.ToString()` o `DynObj.estado.ToString()`.
Además, ¿para qué quieres crear esos datos como variables si con un diccionario puedes recorrer libremente todos los datos? Toma en cuenta que incluso con los páginas Web (lo que adivino que haces por tus `Response`), antes de servir el `aspx` o el `cshtml` éste se tiene que compilar, no puedes estar agregando las variables así como así.

Lee sobre el tema:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033675/how-do-i-name-variables-dynamically-in-c#5033731

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/09b93506-8ea3-4d5c-bf83-24f7daa032bc/creating-variables-at-runtime?forum=csharpgeneral

http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?433691-Create-Variable-at-runtime

http://foro.elhacker.net/programacion_cc/crear_variable_en_runtime_con_nombre_propio-t301566.0.html;msg1495340

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, la separación como ustedes lo mencionan ya la he hecho, utilizando Newtonsoft.Json, aquí tomo los valores fijos que por ahora me arroja, pero si en algún momento el contenido del json cambia, si le agregan o le quitan valores o el último de los casos yo no sepa que valores trae el json, como poder separarlos sin llegar a saber el contenido, quizá sea algo ilógico, pero quiero ver si existe la forma.

Comment: Creo que te entiendo, actualicé mi respuesta.

Comment: ¿Bien, partiendo de la actualización de tu respuesta ya no sería necesario tener el Objeto Persona, ni asignar al modelo persona los datos?, Partiendo del parseo directo:
persona = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Persona>(el_json);

Comment: Exacto, te olvidas del objeto Persona y del parseo directo, solo mantienes la línea de `var personaIntermedioObject = JObject.Parse(el_json);` y le pones un nombre más _genérico_, del estilo `var JsonObj = JObject.Parse(el_json);`; no importan los nombres de las propiedades ni sus valores ni la cantidad de éstos ni sus tipos de dato.

Comment: JObject Resultado = JObject.Parse(EsValido);
Dictionary<string, object> dicRes = Resultado.ToObject<Dictionary<string, object>>();
 foreach (JProperty obj in Resultado.Properties())
     Response.Write(obj.Name + "\n|\n" + obj.Value.ToString() + "<br/>");

Perfecto ya logré mostrar los resultados, ahora necesito crear variables y almacenar sus valores.

Algo asi:

Var nombre = Juan
Var edad = 24

Comment: No puedes crear variables "on the fly". Actualicé la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Considerando lo dinámico de los datos utiliza un Diccionario.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = "{'Nombre':'Juan','Apellido':'Luna','Edad':26,'FechaNacimiento':'09/03/1990 12:00:00 AM'}";

        Dictionary <string,string> jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,string>>(json);

        foreach(var item in jsonObj.Keys){
            Console.WriteLine("Llave: {0} \r\n\t\t\t\tValor: {1}", item, jsonObj[item]);
        }

    }
}
```

El querer crear Propiedades dinámicas solo agregaría complejidad, con este acercamiento puedes ir guardando los Keys que vas recibiendo para tener un Catalogo de valores que puedes usar para modelar el rango posible de datos que recibirías del servicio.